# Mysql Stored Procedure use

Tags: mysql

We have a large database and we do manipulations on it ever day by using the basic mysql queries.

Can anyone please tell me, what is the use of Mysql Stored Procedures?

Comment: You can review http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569 and then ask specific question, if need be.

Answer (score 0):

The real use of the Stored Procedures comes into picture when have any application accessing database.

**For example:** Imagine that you have written all your database operations in the form of queries in your data access code.

Suppose, that you need to make any change to query , then you need to rebuild and redeploy the entire application in order see your changes.

But, if you are using stored procs and refering them in application, you can just make changes in your database with out need for **redeploying** the application.

So, obviously better `security` , `maintainability` and much more

**Note:** This is one scenario where stored procs are better than normal queries.

Usage of Stored Procs also avoids `SQL Injection Attacks`

Comment: Thank you so much, Can you please provide more info with real time examples.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple words, stored procedures allow you to store your quires along with database, you can combine multiple quires in single procedure. now whenever you want to execute those quires just "CALL yourProcedure;"

**Need to perform specific query daily ?**

Read about MySQL events = stored procedures with scheduling capability !

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: Thank you so much, the info you have provided is very useful.